# Perform COUNT on joined tables without a GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by

Is there a way for me to perform a COUNT on joined tables without having to use the GROUP BY statement?
I have to insert this SQL into a legacy application which is parsing this result but can't handle the GROUP BY part.

This is what I have now (works in sql-server, but not in the other app):

```
SELECT TOP 10 au.pref_language,au.username,am.IsOpenIdAccount,am.facebookid,au.sex,au.firstname,au.middlename,au.lastname,am.email,
c.id AS objectid,c.title AS objecttitle,c.friendlyurl as objecturl,c.objecttype,am.CreateDate,c.description_nl,c.description_en,
COUNT(distinct ap.id) as totalphotos,
COUNT(distinct ar.id) as totalreviews,
COUNT(distinct fm.id) as totalfreemedia
FROM locations c
INNER JOIN aspnet_users au on au.UserId=c.userid
INNER JOIN aspnet_membership am ON am.userid=au.userid 
LEFT JOIN location_photos ap on ap.objectid=c.id
LEFT JOIN location_reviews ar on ar.objectid=c.id
LEFT JOIN freemedia fm on fm.objectid=c.id AND fm.objecttype=c.objecttype
WHERE c.title<>''
GROUP BY au.pref_language,au.username,am.IsOpenIdAccount,am.facebookid,au.sex,au.firstname,au.middlename,au.lastname,am.email,
c.id ,c.title ,c.friendlyurl ,c.objecttype,am.CreateDate,c.description_nl,c.description_en
```

And I need something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 au.pref_language,au.username,am.IsOpenIdAccount,am.facebookid,au.sex,au.firstname,au.middlename,au.lastname,am.email,
c.id AS objectid,c.title AS objecttitle,c.friendlyurl as objecturl,c.objecttype,am.CreateDate,c.description_nl,c.description_en,
COUNT(distinct ap.id) as totalphotos,
COUNT(distinct ar.id) as totalreviews,
COUNT(distinct fm.id) as totalfreemedia
FROM locations c
INNER JOIN aspnet_users au on au.UserId=c.userid
INNER JOIN aspnet_membership am ON am.userid=au.userid 
LEFT JOIN location_photos ap on ap.objectid=c.id
LEFT JOIN location_reviews ar on ar.objectid=c.id
LEFT JOIN freemedia fm on fm.objectid=c.id AND fm.objecttype=c.objecttype
WHERE c.title<>''
```

Comment: Does the app parse the SQL before sending it to SQL Server? Maybe instead you could put your query into a stored procedure and tell your app to call that. The query should be a black box to your application. There is no good reason to come up with wacky workarounds for valid SQL that your application can't comprehend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use a view in Sql then run a Select from it?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwMyView]
AS
    SELECT TOP 10 au.pref_language,au.username,am.IsOpenIdAccount,am.facebookid,au.sex,au.firstname,au.middlename,au.lastname,am.email,
    c.id AS objectid,c.title AS objecttitle,c.friendlyurl as objecturl,c.objecttype,am.CreateDate,c.description_nl,c.description_en,
    COUNT(distinct ap.id) as totalphotos,
    COUNT(distinct ar.id) as totalreviews,
    COUNT(distinct fm.id) as totalfreemedia
    FROM locations c
    INNER JOIN aspnet_users au on au.UserId=c.userid
    INNER JOIN aspnet_membership am ON am.userid=au.userid 
    LEFT JOIN location_photos ap on ap.objectid=c.id
    LEFT JOIN location_reviews ar on ar.objectid=c.id
    LEFT JOIN freemedia fm on fm.objectid=c.id AND fm.objecttype=c.objecttype
    WHERE c.title<>''
    GROUP BY au.pref_language,au.username,am.IsOpenIdAccount,am.facebookid,au.sex,au.firstname,au.middlename,au.lastname,am.email,
    c.id ,c.title ,c.friendlyurl ,c.objecttype,am.CreateDate,c.description_nl,c.description_en

    GO
```

Then from your App that parses simply type:

```
    SELECT 
        pref_language,
        username,
        IsOpenIdAccount,
        facebookid,
        sex,
        firstname,
        middlename,
        lastname,
        email,
        objectid,
        objecttitle,
        objecturl,
        objecttype,
        CreateDate,
        description_nl,
        description_en,
        totalPhotos,
        totalReviews,
        totalFreeMedia
    from [dbo].vwMyView
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't see the exact things this app is doing to the input SQL statement. And no one knows who built it anymore. So your suggestion is worth a try...how would I go about that?

Comment: @Floran ? Create a view with your code, test that it returns the data that you want, then send your application `SELECT col1, col2 ... FROM dbo.view_name;`

Comment: The view solution might work. However, the app appends this SQL to any input SQL "AND c.id NOT IN (SELECT objectid FROM emailssent WHERE objecttype=c.objecttype AND emailid=38)". So it expects a column c.id. So I now end up with this: SELECT * FROM [dbo].vwProfileCompleteness WHERE title<>'' AND c.id NOT IN (SELECT objectid FROM emailssent WHERE objecttype=c.objecttype AND emailid=38). I needed to append this "WHERE title<>''" to my SQL since the app appends a string starting with "AND". But apparenty "WHERE title<>''" also doesn't work since I cant access individual columns within a view?

Comment: So modify your view to include the ID field, which you won't be able to do easily, but using the current view definition as a subquery you could easily wrap another query around it to bring in the ID field.   Once that is done simply alias your main table as C, and allow the App to append the where clause you defined, not a problem